# Django if statement not correct

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this.  I have a loop that's printing out a couple of email addresses.  I want to set one as the "primary" address based on it's status of primary or not.  If I give the template {{ x.primary }} I get the values of True or False.

I'd like my output to look like:

- Work: bob@example.com (Primary)
- Personal: bob2@example.com
- Personal: bob3@example.com

---

```
<ul>
{% for x in member.person.email_addresses.all %}
    {% if x.publish %}
       <li> {{ x.type }}: {{ x.email }} {% if x.primary == "True" %} (Primary) {% endif %} </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't quote `True`. It's just `True`:

```
{% if x.primary == True %}
```

Or more simply:

```
{% if x.primary %}
```

Comment: I've used your latter comment in the past, not sure why I didn't again, thanks!  (Still green, sorry)